# Facing error "System.IO.FileNotFoundException:"

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, wmi

I am a C guy and new to C#, I have to debug an error in my project code.
Need help from C# experts,  I read some articles on SO, but was not able to find solution.

I installed SQL 2012 express edition on my Windows 2012 server machine and was trying to run the below code.
 Used Visual Studio 2010.

```
using System;
using System.Management;

public class Example
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        ManagementScope scope = new ManagementScope(@"\\" + Environment.MachineName + @"\root\Microsoft\SQLServer\ComputerManagement11");

        string instanceName, ipAddressName, propertyName, protocolName;
        using (ManagementClass networkProtocolMan = new ManagementClass(scope, new ManagementPath("ServerNetworkProtocolProperty"), null))
        {
            networkProtocolMan.Get();
            Console.WriteLine("" + networkProtocolMan.Path);         
            ManagementObjectCollection moCollection = networkProtocolMan.GetInstances(); //Class gets filled with error here
                                                                                        //used debugger to look inside moCollection   
            Console.WriteLine(""+moCollection.Count); //Error is getting printed on console here
            ManagementObject mo;
            ManagementObject protocolProperty = null; ;
        }
        return;
    }
}
```

The error which I get is:

> System.IOFileNotFoundException:
>
> at
>   System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.ThrowExceptionForHRInternal
>        at System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.ThrowExceptionForHR
>       at System.Management.ManagementObjectCollection.ManagementObjectEnumeration.moveNext<>
>
> at System.Management.ManagementObjectCollection.get_Count<>

After putting breakpoints I see that in moCollection->Count value is

> 'moclooection.Count' threw an exception of type 'System.IO.FileNotFound'
>   and type is: int{System.IO.FileNotFoundException}

I was not able to post the debugger screenshot here, so I tried it to describe as above. Please guide me to resolve this error.

Comment: what does this have to do with sql server?

Comment: see this "\root\Microsoft\SQLServer\ComputerManagement11"

Comment: I installed 64 bit SQL Server 2012

Comment: The error means that the WMI path doesn't exist. This is a WMI question. Try testing your path [first as shown here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms179546.aspx) to ensure that you can use it

Comment: If you can't connect using WBEMTest, there may be a permissions problem or a problem with your WMI provider registration, eg as described in this [KB article]9https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/956013)

Comment: @Panagiotis Kanavos  The code runs fine till Get(), At GetInstance() it fills moCollection with errors, I will look into solution provided by you.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I had tried "**SELECT * FROM ServerNetworkProtocolProperty where InstanceName="TCS"  and  ProtocolName = "sm"** " with WBEMTEST tool it is working fine, not showing any error. The same code is working for SQL Server 2012 32 bit but not working for 64 bit.

Comment: Sounds like what the KB article describes. Did you check it?